# Complex list display using recycler view in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My data structure looks like the following:

```
{
  "schedules": [
    {
      "date": "Tue Sep 20 2017",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "John Doe",
          "category": "CCC"
        },
        {
          "name": "John Doe",
          "category": "CCCU-A"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "Wed Sep 21 2017",
      "slots": [
        {
          "name": "John Doe",
          "category": "CCCU-A"
        },
        {
          "name": "John Doe",
          "category": "CCCU-A"
        }
      ]
    }
]
}
```

How can I use this kind of data in a recycler view? I  want to display the date as the header and the slots as items under the header. I have tried using two recycler views. One recycler view inside other. But the problem is when I scroll the screen, I can see huge blank gaps. I have tried changing the height of the second recycler view to wrap_content but that doesn't seem to help. I also tried to use list view inside the recylcer view. But I was able to see just the first item in the list. The other items had to be scrolled in order to be viewed. I have seen other posts that mention about switching the view holder and using just one recycler view. These articles I noticed have used flat data. So any ideas on how to proceed with this issue will help me greatly.

Comment: When asking questions that involves direct UI modifications, it's better to add a screenshot of the observed UI and occasionally the expected UI.

Answer (score 0):

Add cardView inside recyclerView. It will definitely solve your problem as well as you will be able to change UI according to your need with very few changes in cardView.

If you don't know about making cards, then go through this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/).